# Advanced Chart Formatting in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I feel like an absolute idiot.
I want to modify the Colors my Charts (Bar Graph) uses for it's series.
Every single Google Search leads me to the Jaspersoft community referring me to "Chart Formatting" but no matter how hard I look, I cannot find this option anywhere in the Studio.

If I go to "Properties" and Search for "Color" I see a menu called "Series Color" but when I open that menu I get 2 Nullpointer Exceptions and any change I make there will not be saved.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known Problem with Jaspersoft Studio 6.13, that is still present in 6.14 but was not present in 6.12.2, I therefore switched back for the time being